# Most idiomatic way to console.log

Tags: clojurescript

These two format produces `console.log("Hello")`.

```
(.log js/console "Hello")
(js/console.log "Hello")
(console.log "Hello")
```

Is one form more idiomatic than the other?

Edit: I also noticed `(console.log)` also works (only tested with shadow-cljs)

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion is that `(js/console.log "Hello")` is more frequently used in the wild, but that both forms are idiomatic.

If you are looking for guidance as to which one to use, `(.log js/console "Hello")` feels more “correct,” while `(js/console.log "Hello")` feels to me like you are embedding a little bit of JavaScript in your ClojureScript (by abusing dots in symbols to achieve nested property access).

I say this even though Rich [used this very construct](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/954e8529b1ec814f40af77d6035f90e93a9126ea#diff-a9cce52f0bf5a7b9afccbec54e4a0e4bR39) when he first introduced the `js` pseudo-namespace.

One general advantage of employing “normal” interop constructs is that the compiler can help you. For example, try

```
(defn set-top [console antenna]
  (js/console.log "Hello"))
```

and call this via `(set-top :x :y)`. You will get a mysterious error indicating

```
TypeError: console.log is not a function
```

But if instead you write

```
(defn set-top [console antenna]
  (.log js/console "Hello"))
```

you will get an extremely helpful warning *at compile time*:

```
WARNING: js/console is shadowed by a local
```

This is because you are writing *ClojureScript* and not *embedding JavaScript semantics within a ClojureScript symbol*, and thus the ClojureScript compiler can help you.